# c# pass class inheritance from generic abstract class in generic param

Tags: c#, generics, inheritance, abstract-class, type-constraints

I have this tree interfaces/classes

> BaseRepository.cs

```
abstract public class BaseRepository<Entity> : IRepository
    where Entity : BaseEntity, new()
{
    public virtual IList<Entity> FindAll()
    {
        ...
        return list;
    }
}
```

Try to automatize the Get, Update, Insert webapi creation with generics

> BaseApiController

```
public class BaseEntityApiController<Repository> : ApiController
    where Repository : BaseRepository<BaseEntity>, new()
{
    Repository repository = new Repository();

    public IList<BaseEntity> Get()
    {
         return repository.FindAll();
    }

}
```

> UserRepository

```
public class UserRepository : BaseRepository<User>
{  
}
```

I created a new controller that inheritance from BaseApiController passing the UserRepository:

> UserController

```
public class UserController : BaseApiController<UserRepository>
{
}
```

I receive this error:

```
Project.UserRepository cannot be used as type parameters 'Repository' in the generic type or method 'BaseApiController<Repository>'. There is no implicit reference conversion from Project.UserRepository to Project BaseRepository<Project.BaseEntity>.
```

How can i pass my UserRepository with generic type to my BaseApiController to automatize the creation of Api used in all controllers?

Comment: Does `User` inherit from `BaseEntity`?

Comment: @Flater yes User inherit from BaseEntity

Comment: I would put access modifiers before than abstract.

`code` public abstract  class BaseRepository<Entity> : IRepository `code`

Answer (score 3):

Add a generic type argument for the entity type to your `BaseEntityApiController` definition:

```
public class BaseEntityApiController<TRepository, TEntity> : ApiController
    where TRepository : BaseRepository<TEntity>, new()
    where TEntity : BaseEntity, new()
{
    // ...
}
```

Comment: it works but my goal is that not define two generic because the Repository have the TEntity the i need defined in this inheritance (TEntity is my <User>):

 public class UserRepository : BaseRepository<User>
{  
}

Comment: You can have it working this way or your way and broken.  Including the `TEntity` type argument isn't a problem - the generic type constraints will ensure you don't mix and match different entity types for the repo/entity args.

You could also remove the generic type argument for `Repository` and construct your `Repository` object via reflection using `TEntity`, but there wouldn't be compile-time checking that the `Repository<T>` implementation has a parameterless constructor.

Comment: yeah i tried change my Entity in baseApi generic declaration and a error compired. I think the first solution is the best. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

make sure:

```
public class User: BaseEntity
{  
}
```

you probably want a double generic as well:

```
public class BaseEntityApiController<Repository, BaseEntity> : ApiController
    where Repository : BaseRepository<BaseEntity>, new()
{
    Repository repository = new Repository();

    public IList<BaseEntity> Get()
    {
         return repository.FindAll();
    }

}
```

This way you wont have to cast things like:

```
UserController.Get().Cast<User>()
```

just do:

```
public class UserController : BaseEntityApiController<UserRepository, User>{}
UserController.Get()
```

one time double defining generic vs. constantly casting from BaseEntity to User

Comment: i received a error in BaseEntityApiControlle:

the type 'BaseEntity' cannot be used as type parameters 'Entity' in the generic type or method 'BaseRepository<Entity>'. There is no boxing conversion or type parameter conversion from 'BaseEntity' To 'Project.BaseEntity'

'BaseEntity' must be a non-abstract type with a public parameterless constructor in order to use it as parameter 'Entity' in the generic type or method 'BaseRepository<Entity>'

Comment: adding the code posted by moho i don't receive any error but my goal is not specific two time the Entity Generic because the repository know what is the entity to use. There is any change to not repeat it?

Comment: Yes use generic Co or contravariance